# Where to remove iOS updates of iOS latest versions on file system of a rooted iOS device?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I have been trying to remove OTA updates of version 11.4.1 from settings> general> iPad storage but nothing is happening.
Moreover, I have a jailbroken device therefore it should be fairly easy to remove updates from system folders is there a watcher service to see the latest changes in file structure or specific location as wanted to manually remove updates or create a script to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the tvOS beta profile to prevent your device from downloading the update file.

If you are already jailbroken, there are many tweaks that disable this feature, just look for them on Cydia.

Comment: As per my observation there are non available at the moment, moreover each application should have a specific directory of updates but OTA updates are not visible in regular location.